# How do I add list elements to Angular when a button is pressed?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Ok, so I am working on a website that will be used to control a robot, and I want to be able to input latitude and longitude coordinates, press a button, and then add those coordinates to an angular list element.

[image]

Here's an image of the website. The two input fields and the button are in the far right card. Basically, I want to be able to type in the latitude and longitude, hit the 'Add Waypoint' button, and then I want the list element to update with that information.

Here is my html code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols = "8" rowHeight = 350px>
<mat-grid-tile style = "background-color: royalblue;" colspan = "2">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Rotation Data</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <mat-slider class="slider" [(ngModel)] = "sliderVal1"></mat-slider>
            <mat-progress-bar
              class = "example-margin"
              [color] = "color"
              [mode] = "mode"
              [value] = "sliderVal1"
              [bufferValue] = "sliderVal1">
            </mat-progress-bar>
            <p>Pitch: {{sliderVal1}}</p>
    
            <mat-slider class="slider" [(ngModel)] = "sliderVal2"></mat-slider>
            <mat-progress-bar
              class = "example-margin"
              [color] = "color"
              [mode] = "mode"
              [value] = "sliderVal2"
              [bufferValue] = "sliderVal2">
            </mat-progress-bar>
            <p>Roll: {{sliderVal2}}</p>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>

<mat-grid-tile style = "background-color: royalblue;"  colspan = "2">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Driving Controls</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <p>Speed: {{sliderVal3}}</p>
            <mat-slider class="slider" [(ngModel)] = "sliderVal3"></mat-slider>
    
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <p>Turning: {{sliderVal4}}</p>
            <mat-slider class="slider" [(ngModel)] = "sliderVal4"></mat-slider>
    
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <p>Configuration Mode: 0</p>
            <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Default Driving</button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>1</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>2</button>
            </mat-menu>
    
            <div class = "reset-button">
                <button mat-button color="primary" (click) = "resetControls()">Reset Controls</button>
            </div>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>

<mat-grid-tile style = "background-color: royalblue;" colspan = "4">
    <mat-card class = "colspan-4">
        <mat-card-title>Waypoints</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <mat-grid-list cols = "3" rowHeight = "85px">
                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Latitude</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="latValue">
                        <button *ngIf="latValue" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="latValue=''">
                          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-form-field>     
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Longitude</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="lonValue">
                        <button *ngIf="lonValue" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="lonValue=''">
                          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-form-field>                          
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <button mat-button color="primary">Add Waypoint</button>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-list>
                        <div mat-subheader>Waypoints</div>
                        <mat-list-item>
                            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>place</mat-icon>
                            <div mat-line>Waypoint 1</div>
                            <div mat-line>{{latValue}}, {{lonValue}}</div>
                        </mat-list-item>
                    </mat-list>
                </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array of waypoints aswell as a method to add them in your component.ts:

```
  waypoints: {lat: number, lon: number}[] = [];

  addWaypoint() {
    this.waypoints.push({lat: this.latValue, lon: this.lonValue});
  }
```

Add a click event to your button:

```
<button (click)="addWaypoint()">Add Waypoint</button>
```

Iterate your waypoints with *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let waypoint of waypoints">
    <div>{{waypoint.lat}}, {{waypoint.lon}}</div>
</div>
```

I used a div here, but you can just use *ngFor in every element (mat-list-item in your case).